# Replacing stock Core 2 Duo heatsink fan (just the fan really) with a Dell CPU fan

Tags: heatsink, fan

My old heatsink fan broke and I'm trying to reconnect its plugs to a new fan. My Dell CPU fan has some custom Dell plug.  I snipped the old fan's wire in half and kept the plug on the end of it.  I want to connect it to the Dell fan wire to the plug.

The motherboard is a P5Q-e, the stock Core 2 Duo fan was .20A and the dell is .70A.  Is that going to matter?

The wire from the fan has four wires, the wire with the plug has four wires.  They share three, of the four colors: red, black, and blue.  Dell's fourth wire is white, while the plug's fourth wire is yellow.

Is it safe to assume that I just connect the yellow and the white plug together and match the rest up?

I don't want to take any risk of damaging anything.  It runs fine passively without a fan, but I have speedstep on, so I would like to use this fan and just fasten it to the heatsink with some twist ties and paperclips and call it a day.

Comment: Most common Dell fans use 5 pin 4 wire PWM:
Black=Ground
Red=12v
White=RPM
Blue=PWM 
So says the web.  Many people who changed to a different fan on the dells the computer would not boot, till they put the dell fan back.  because their dell was expecting a specific RPM and might have a specific Sence or divisor or whaever for the fan they use.  The Power specs no problem, but a delta is usually very high rpm.  So this is just a note , if you dont get boot, it is just that the dell doesnt think the fan is working (or fast enough)

Answer (score 3):

It's a Dell component, it's not intended to neatly work with any non-Dell system. You are better off purchasing a new one.

Here's further reasoning:

Dell manufacturers every component for their systems (that are not PCI style riser cards and that are not drives, CPU or RAM) to be specific to their systems.

The wiring is often non-standard, the PSU mounts and connectors are often non-standard, and they are intended to make it difficult for you to purchase non-Dell components and install them into your system. This ensures that Dell continues to make a profit.

Sidenote: Yes, that does suck. In the future, don't purchase Dell and support them. However, for the needs of 90% of the population (statistics, that field where all numbers are approximately made up) this is a viable solution, because customers want fixes *that work* and not fixes *that save more money in the short term*.

***EDIT***

Additionally, the manual for that board says that the five headers support 1A - 7A of fan at +12V so as far as amperage you should be fine. That's on page 2.34 (number 8) of the latest English manual for that board from their website.

Comment: So you're saying that if I do what I have outlined above the fan will not work?  It's a Delta fan model EFC0912BF.

Comment: What I'm saying is that it's not likely to work. I'm not saying it won't work. I'm also arguing against "just stripping the wires and mating them up" because it's designed _not_ to work in your system.

Comment: I don't think you know what you're talking about.  Someone else please help.  And thanks for chucking me in the common denominator pile with that snobby post.  I have been building my own PCs for more than a decade now and I have never owned a Dell.  I am not sure what you think they do to their fans besides change the connectors on them.  Anything more than that would not make business sense.  I have never learned about electrical engineering and looking for someone who has, not just someone using specious reasoning.

Comment: actually, no, most dells these days seem to have dropped the stupid non standard parts thing. The case is still a PITA to work with, but i have not found one non standard part in the older dell i use as a spare system

Comment: First off, it took two passes for you to think I chucked you in the LCD pile? I didn't. I was just pointing out their reasons why. For the second, I've been building them for ~17 years now, so you can put your epeen away. Third: I've built systems for HP in their factory, I've worked with elec engineers building specific devices for integrated markets, I've got many many hours logged on soldering irons, and I have found that it's not worth the hassle to try and re-use a Dell HSF on non-Dell systems. As for the voltage/amperage specs, idk exactly.

Comment: The board should handle that level of amperage for that fan with no substantial problem, but you snipped all the wires before you tested, how can you know for sure what's supposed to mate up where. The colors probably will match, cos engineers like things to match, but you're talking about making one hell of a mess inside your box with tape and the like. It'll improve airflow, reduce less future problems, and look cleaner (and things that look a certain way tend to go that way) and look like it's supposed to work. Regardless if it _does_ work, it'll look like it should work.

Comment: Additionally @user647345, you'll find that my first suggestion would have involved a desktop power supply and a set of probes, but not for the person who has been so reckless as to go ahead and cut the headers off at the cable, as you insinuated you did in your first post. I only snip my cable headers off at the time of remating, once I know it is going to work like I expected, not haphazardly at the beginning.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek that is not my experience with current Dell commodity hardware. I'm wide open to being told I'm wrong by definitive sources, but it's my current _experience_ that that is not accurate definitively. C'est la vie.

Comment: @user647345 `I am not sure what you think they do to their fans besides change the connectors on them` well you said it yourself: `the stock Core 2 Duo fan was .20A and the dell is .70A` they build them for their own needs and purposes, which includes using whatever amperage they see fit. So between custom headers and different amperages, what else would you like to see them do to declare them different? Different volts as well?

Comment: After doing some research and learning how 4-pin PWM fans work I have went on and did it.  I have connected white and yellow wires, which seem to be the 'control wire' used to vary the speed of the fan.  Everything works, even mobo's fan speed control.

Comment: And yeah, the fans had different amperage not because "they [who are they?] build them for their own needs and purposes", but because fans come in all different sizes and capacities.  I can buy a Vantec fan, a SilenX fan, a Zalman fan and they will all have different amperage. This happened to be a Delta fan which are actually very common.

Comment: Jcolebrand, honestly, you sound like someone who never even built a computer before.  What the hell are you talking about half the time?  CPU fans or any computer fan is 12v.  And what are you talking about "five headers support"? Who's talking about 5-pin fans?  I just don't understand where you're coming from, it all seems to be like point-whoring and not knowing what you're talking about.  I'm done, thanks for your help.

Comment: "I don't think you know what you're talking about" this is where you would be wrong, you are trying to use a special PWM fan on a standard motherboard connector, even if you get the correct wires to the correct pins it will sound like a jet airplane and run at full speed, which is incredibly fast on that type of fan, good luck.

Comment: Here is the typical Dell pinout chart for a PWM fan...http://pinouts.ru/Motherboard/dell_fan_pinout.shtml

Comment: @user647345 "five headers support" um, that board has five fan headers. The things you plug into. It's in the manual. It's funny how when I was curious, I went to the manual. Like I do on all systems I repair. Funny that.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently managed to fit a arctic cooling f8 pwm 80mm fan in my dell 760 sff.

#### This is how I did it.

- I cut the dell plug off left about 2" of wire,
- I connected the following wires from the new fan to the dell plug:

  - Yellow to red 12 volt supply
  - Green to yellow sensor
  - Blue to Blue PWM
  - Black to black earth ground

The wires on the dell plug are:

- Red 12 volt
- Yellow sensor
- Blue PWM
- Black earth ground

The wires on the fan are:

- Yellow 12 volt
- Green sensor
- Blue PWM
- Black earth ground

It works great and is quieter and you get no beep codes, also I removed the hard drive fan and simply spliced the yellow sensor cable from the hard drive fan to the cpu fan yellow cable plugged the hard drive fan plug back into the m/b no errors or beeps nice quiet pc which still runs cool.

My next project is fit a 2.5 hard drive in between the cd rom re-writer so the m/b has plenty of cooling.

Hope my info as helped out.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser Paul, properly formatted answers are easier to follow.